# excel formula suggestion required

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Based on the -2 or +2 entry, we would like to paint range with yellow. Need your suggestions to fix it.

Question updated:

Sorry for poor explanation. I have column A, B, C.  if I enter -2 in B10, A10,A9,A8 will be colored. If  I enter +2 in C10, A10,A11, A12 will be colored.
The value I can enter in B is -10 to -1 and C is 1 to 10. **So the *formula* that i can use in *conditional format* should be more generic.**

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for "Conditional Format" in Excel?

Comment: And could you explain more about "Based on the -2 or +2"?

Comment: Excel formulas on their own cannot control/reference colour to the best of my knowledge.  However, formulas placed within conditional formatting can allow conditional formulas to change colours.  Second part, as prisoner suggest, is how are the -2 and +2 controlling what cells get coloured?  a more detailed explanation on what they are referencing or how the limits are determined based on the -2 and +2 would be VERY helpful.

Answer (score 2):

this might be useful for you.

```
Sub yellow()

    Dim i As Integer

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For k = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(k, 1).Value = 2 Or Cells(k, 1).Value = -2 Then
    Cells(k, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: I asked for a formula not vba code. I am down voting.

Comment: @NSN did you answer the questions on the comments section?

Comment: @Apurv I have upvoted to appreciate your effort on helping others

Answer (score 1):

**Revised.  Now I think I got what you want.**

According to your description, here is what you can do:

- To avoid the end users enter any invalid number in `column B or C`, use `Data > Data Validation`.  See the attached pic below for example on how to setup rules for `column B`.  Please adjust the criteria accordingly to fit your need.

[image]

P.S. This pic below just to show you when an end user entered a value that is out of the specified range, it would show an error message.

[image]

- To display the color coded cell depends on the value that you enter in `cell B10` or `cell C10`, select `Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...`.  I used this formula `=ROW($A1)-10>=$B$10`, and applied to `=$A$1:$A$10`.  Then `=ROW($A10)-10<=$C$10`, and applied to `=$A$10:$A$20` as you can see two pics below.

[image]

[image]

This is to determine the row position and the value that the user entered.  You may want to change that -10 to `ROW($B$10)` or `ROW($C$10)` for dynamic purpose but that is up to you.

Please note that `cell A10` got referenced twice on the conditional formatting.  Whichever rule goes first will show that color and you can change the order by clicking the arrow sign that shows on pic#4.

Please try again and let me know if this works or not.

Comment: let me try, how i can generalise it. because if B10 = -3, 3 rows (backwards) need to be highlighted. same if C10=4, 4 rows forward need to be done.

Comment: @NSN, I have revised my answer.  Please take a look and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Will give a try and let you know.  >>> Please note that cell A10 got referenced twice on the conditional formatting. Whichever rule goes first will show that color and you can change the order by clicking the arrow sign that shows on pic#4.<<<

We use the same color for both +ve and -ve. hence not an issue.